# Passing parameters using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have made this web service where I have passed 2 parameters:

```
http://192.168.0.106/PdfReportWebservice.asmx/LoginDetails?UserID=jay&Password=jay
```

I want to use these parameters to log in by making a function and passing it `onclick` of a button.

For now the values are hardcoded, but I will b using data from my database. Can anyone please help me know how I can pass parameters using JavaScript or AngularJS to extract data from database to log in? And also giving message for valid or invalid credentials?

Comment: Are you using routing in it?

Comment: Hey soumya can you please write some code, what u tried so far?

Comment: im very new to this so i dont know how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to make a HTTP/Rest call you can use the angular $**resource** for that.

Now passing passing parameters should be fairly simple if you follow the documentation for **$resource**.

```
    var resource = $resource('your rest endpoint goes here');      
    return resource.query({
        paramA : paramAValue,
        paramB: paramBValue
    }, function(result, headers) {
    if (result.length && result.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            //Your Logic Here... You can replace 'query' with your desired method
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: is this the way u extract the parameters from the URL?

Comment: This is how you send the values to the server. The values will be appended to the URL and the resulting query string will be sent to the server.

Comment: and could you tell me how to extract it please?

Comment: Extract where ?? On the client side or on the server side ?

Comment: This is actually for a login page of a mobile application.so i want to get the parameters inserted on the login page n got to validate it for valid or invalid user.

Comment: resource.query({
        UserID: $scope.userID,
        Password: $scope.password
    }